# Prestashop back-office load slow except page module

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop

I'm recently installed Prestashop version 1.7, however, I have a problem loading pages from my backoffice except for the Module page.

Indeed, when I browse my back-office pages partially loads and the ajax load is always in infinity loading.

Can you help me solve my problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)